# newbie ask about decimal to binary in c++

Tags: c++

this program suppose to convert decimal to binary but somehow i screw it up

can some one point out the error for me?

thanks a lot

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int a;
    int b[20];
    int q = 0;
    printf("decimal : ");scanf("%d",&a);
    while(a>0)) {
        b[q]=a%2;
        a=a/2;      
        q++;

        }while(a>0);
    printf("binary : ");

    for (int i = q-1; i>=0;i--){
        printf("%d",b[q]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  This looks like straight C code.

Comment: so does this not compile because `while(a>0))` or do you have a different issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code is:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    int b[20];
    int q = 0;
    printf("decimal : ");scanf("%d",&a);
    while(a>0) {
        b[q]=a%2;
        a=a/2;      
        q++;

    }
    printf("binary : ");

    for (int i = q-1; i>=0;i--){
        printf("%d",b[i]);
    }

}
```

You were printing b[q] instead of b[i]

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code:

1. you added an extra ")" of the first while;
2. the second 'while' is useless (the code is being repeated due to the first one)
3. you are not printing the elements you want (you should use var 'i'), what you are really printing is the value after the last 0/1 (because you are using 'q')

code should look like this:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int b[20];
    int q = 0;
    printf("decimal: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    while (a > 0) {
        b[q] = a % 2;
        a = a / 2;
        q++;
    }
    printf("binary: ");
    for (int i = q - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", b[i]);
    }
}
```